# UIAlertview text field size issue

Tags: ios, uialertview

I'm developing an application, which requires a lot of input from the user side. For this, I'm using UIAlertview's "alertViewStyle" property to display an alert with plainTextInput format. It works fine. But, while running the application on iPhone 4, the size of UIAlertview's text field is very small, such that the user input is not visible on the text field. Is there a way to increase the size of UIAlertview's built-in text field?

Ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Which version of _iOS_ are you running on?

Comment: Im using Xcode 5.1..

Comment: IOS version is iOS 5